# Django manage.py collectstatic not uploading to google cloud storage

Tags: django, django-settings, django-storage

### **Experience level with issue**

This is my first experience with deploying static files and using Django.

---

### **Issue**

When I run *python manage.py collectstatic*

I will get the following result:

```
2 static files copied to '/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/onbytes.com/onbytes-static', 151 unmodified, 4 post-processed.
```

But nothing is beeing push to my bucket in google cloud storage.  I'm not getting any errors in the terminal. Anything I'm missing her?

---

### My code

I'm using [django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/apache_libcloud.html)

This is the following definition in my setting.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/onbytes.com/static'
STATIC_URL = 'http://storage.googleapis.com/onbytes-static/'

LIBCLOUD_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'type': 'libcloud.storage.types.GOOGLE_STORAGE',
        'user': 'XXXXXX', 
        'key': 'XXXXX',
        'bucket': 'onbytes-static',
    },
}

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.apache_libcloud.LibCloudStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.apache_libcloud.LibCloudStorage'
```

my requirements.txt

```
...
boto==2.30.0
django-pipeline==1.3.25
django-storages==1.1.8
```

Answer (score 3):

Stupid mistake I had another definition in the setting.py linked to Pipeline

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'