# Deploy staticfiles to google bucket using django-google-storage + django-pipeline

Tags: django

I want to deploy my static compress files to my Google Cloud Storage bucket.

As of now I have no issue with only using django-google-storage to deploy but:

How to use django-pipeline **to compress and then deploy** to my bucket.

In the pipeline docs it says:

You can also use your own custom storage, for example, if you want to use S3 for your assets :

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'your.app.S3PipelineStorage'
```

Your storage only need to inherit from PipelineMixin and/or CachedFilesMixin :

```
from staticfiles.storage import CachedFilesMixin

from pipeline.storage import PipelineMixin

from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


class S3PipelineStorage(PipelineMixin, CachedFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    pass
```

How can I apply this for google cloud storage?

**My staticfiles_storgage**

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django-google-storage.storage.GoogleStorage'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the setting to define [linked object via Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700604/django-manage-py-collectstatic-not-uploading-to-google-cloud-storage)

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'
```